# How can find what ^? and ^/ correspond to on a keyboard in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm experimenting with stty by setting the erase key to be something else than backspace.  For example, setting the regular backspace key would be:

```
stty erase ^?
```

If you wanted to make the erase command actually ENTER, so that when you pressed enter in the terminal it actually deleted the last character, what characters would you pass as the argument to stty erase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stty erase ^M
```

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd><key></kbd> to figure out control codes in general.